# How to type object when returning without assignment

Tags: typescript

I can't seem to figure out how to type an object when it's being returned without assignment.

Example:

```
interface Foo{
  a: string;
}

const arr = ['a','b','c'];

arr.map(item => {
  return { a: item }; //I want type safety on Foo here
});

// Don't want to have to do this
arr.map(item => {
  let ret: Foo = { a: item }; //first assign
  return ret;
});
```

I would expect something like `return :Foo { a: item };` to work but it doesn't.  I don't want to use `return { a: item } as Foo;` because it isn't typesafe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could annotate the return type of the arrow function:

```
arr.map((item): Foo => {
  return { a: item }; 
});
```

It's similar to something like

```
arr.map(function f(item): Foo {
  return { a: item }; 
});
```

which uses regular function notation, or the more obvious:

```
function mapper(item: string): Foo {
  return {a: item};
}
arr.map(mapper);
```

Well, except in both arrow functions, the type of `item` is inferred from context to be `string`.  In the standalone function you need to specify `string` explicitly. But in all the examples, the return type is specified as `Foo` and is type safe.

Does that help?

Comment: doh! I should have known that.  Brain fart

Answer (score 2):

This is what generics are usually used for. If a method was typed as generic (`Array` methods were), optional generic parameter can be passed to provide additional type information.

This generic parameter is there exactly to specify callback return type:

[image: map]

It should be:

```
arr.map<Foo>(item => {
  return { a: item };
});
```